# I am unable to see the Full Data(Analysis -> View data) in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop, viewdata

My data contains around 10000 records.

I have published my workbook in the browser. I am able to see the summary and full data in Tableau (2022.1.1) version.

But I am unable to see the content in Full data in View data ( version - 2021.4.8).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, "View Data" is just a preview option for your data and it will only show those fields which belong to the viz used in your dashboard

[image]

Comment: All the required fields, and their data are showing on the Tableau desktop. Once I published the workbook in the browser I am unable to see the Full data records. I can see only column names, not their records/data.